# Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLServerDriver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, azure-sql-database

I have the following code for hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlAzure2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=tcp:usedctp000dbs01.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=usedctp000db01;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={user};Password={password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Password";</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I run BuildSessionFactory I get the following Exception

> NHibernate.HibernateException: 'Could not create the driver from
> NHibernate.Driver.SQLServerDriver.'

I found similar questions but related to MySQL and the solution was to add Mysql.Data.dll, do you know if I should upload a similar file for Azure SQL Server? Which one and where can I find it? I tried adding sqlsrv32.dll but I get the following error
[image]

Comment: You need to add reference to `(System.Data.SqlClient)`

Comment: Do you know where I can find the .dll? It is not available in References Manager List

Comment: If you do `Add Reference...` your project, this should be available in the list of libraries from GAC of on your machine. Alternatively you can try to reference it from Nuget package. Which .NET Version you are using for your project?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/

Answer (score 0):

System.Data.SqlClient was installed
[image]

Also it wasn't present on Reference Manager `Add Reference`
[image]

To solve this I had to find the path of de dll inside the package

[image]
[image]

and add it through the Reference Manage `Add Reference` browsing the file. However a new error is displayed

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type
> NHibernate.Driver.SQLServerDriver. Possible cause: no assembly name
> specified.

We just fix this removing the following line from the configuration

NHibernate.Driver.SQLServerDriver

seems that it is not required, it is automatically detected when you specify the dialect